# What happens when using 1 creative with 2 ad units in DFP Small Business?

Tags: google-dfp

I'm looking for clarification with regard to a recent issue we faced as a DFP Small Business customer.

We have a line item that contained 2 ad units and 1 creative. We were trying to render both units on the same page. With the settings below, the first unit would show the creative and the second unit wouldn't show anything. By duplicating the creative (now 2 creative and 2 slots), now both units are filled.

I'm just looking for any insight on DFP or links to documentation on their site to get some more knowledge. We had been confident that the single creative would be used for both slots, but that's obviously not the case.

**Settings**
- *Type*: sponsorship

**Adjust Delivery**
- *Display Creatives*: One or more
- *Rotate creatives*: Optimized
- *Goal*: 100% of impressions
- *Day and time*: All days and times
- *Frequency*: unchecked for 'set per user frequency cap'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DFP will show a single creative no more than once per page, as highlighted on [this page](http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=82245)... so duplicating the creative like you did is the correct way to go about fixing the issue.